# Android Facebook Key needs to be encrypted when app released?

Tags: android, facebook, encryption

I have an app that connects and updates a users facebook status. I have ofcourse got a key for my app to verify who it is. Does this need to be encrypted and if so how can I achieve this. I have no previous knowledge of encryption and little of java so please could you link to anything useful as well.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to static `App Id` Facebook assigns your application or `access token` you're given during runtime?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its never a bad idea to encrypt any sensitive data.  But if you are using Eclipse and the ADK to develop your app, the whole app is obfuscation with proguard.  (see: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html )  This makes it much harder to find the string, but not impossible.

Its not hard to encyrpt and decript strings in Android.  Here is a short example:
http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings
Something to keep in mind is that eventualy the string will be decrypted in memory and passed to a function.  If someone is running your app in the emulator or device with in circuit emulation they will get the string.  Just be ready for it, and have a plan with how to deal with it.

Comment: How will you prevent the attacker from stealing the encryption key?

Comment: You can't prevent from stealing the encryption key, it just will slow them down a bit.  That's why I was saying that you should have a plan on how to change the key if you need to.